# Getting started with osmdroid - failed to install?

Tags: android, debugging, installation, osmdroid, openstreetmap

I'm new to android. I have some java knowledge (not extensive), and I've done some of the android tutorials. 
I'm trying to use osmdroid at the moment, I just want to get the map to display.
I'm using the code from here: [Help setting up OSMdroid library for displaying OpenSourceMaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241167/help-setting-up-osmdroid-library-for-displaying-opensourcemaps). But when I try to run it (on a virtual device with the correct API level), the console sayes:

```
[2012-02-03 17:24:06 - osmtest] Failed to install osmtest.apk on device 'emulator-5556!
[2012-02-03 17:24:06 - osmtest] (null)
[2012-02-03 17:24:06 - osmtest] Failed to install osmtest.apk on device 'emulator-5556': EOF
[2012-02-03 17:24:06 - osmtest] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: EOF
[2012-02-03 17:24:06 - osmtest] Launch canceled!
```

I still find logcat quite confusing. It sayes: PID 90 tag installd 'Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory'

What could be the problem here? Something I've done wrong with the avd? 
How could I get more useful information from logcat?

**Solution** I hadn't included slf4j in the build path. :) 
So for anyone else with this problem, you download the jar from here: http://www.slf4j.org/android/
and then include it in your build path in the same way you did for osmdroid.jar
(ie. create a lib folder in your project and put the jar there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to mark this question as answered, though I solved this myself in the end. 
I didn't have slf4j included in my project. :)

Comment: If you solved the issue then you should mark your own answer as 'accepted answer' (see the tick at the left).